# How exactly are URLs mapped to handlers in IIS 7+

Tags: iis

I have a website that uses a ReverseProxy (Helicon APE) to forward some requests to external sources. To achieve this it replaces/adds the extension **.apehandler** to the URL, so the Helicon APE Handler executes the request.

> **/ext/app1.aspx** is rewritten to **/ext/app1.apehandler**

This works fine.

When the URL does not end in an extension, there is a problem:

> **/ext/app2.aspx/something**  is rewritten to    **/ext/app2.aspx/something.apehandler**

This leads to URLs with two extensions.

If in the handlermapping order **.apehandler**  is defined *BEFORE*  **.aspx**  all is fine.

But when **.apehandler** is defined *AFTER* **.aspx** the PageHandlerFactory-Handler (.aspx Handler) takes over and this results in a 404 error.

In the Failed Request Log the **URL_CHANGED** entry is the same in both cases, but the **HANDLER_CHANGED** maps to different handlers.

Maybe there is a small problem in how IIS maps URLs to Handlers in this special case?

My guess is when IIS parses the URLs to map to the handler, matching URLs with two or more extensions goes wrong.

> URL  **/ext/app2.aspx/something.apehandler**
>
> IIS parses for .aspx , (wrongly?) finds it in above URL and executes the .aspx Handler

Any ideas?

swobi

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is wrong.

When `/ext/app2.aspx/something.apehandler` is seen by IIS, it passes path_info of `/somthing.apehandler` to `/ext/app2.aspx`. Of course then .aspx handler is called to process it, not the Helicon APE Handler.

It is not just IIS, but all web frameworks that must handle path_info that way. You can find a PHP reference [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: So IIS parses from the left side for the extension?

`/ext2/app2.aspx/something.apehandler`
parsed for **.aspx** 
sets PATH_INFO `/something.apehandler`

`/ext2/app2.aspx/something.apehandler`
parsed for **.apehandler** also matches

and whatever handler is defined first wins.